# ¿Cómo corro el menu navbar de bootstrap hacia la derecha?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Busqué muchas maneras y aun no consigo hacerlo, estoy usando bootstrap 4.1

Este es mi código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary n1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01"></div>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav text-aligned justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: si quieres imagen en html y añadiendole estilo con Bootstrap añade una etiqueta img con su respectivo src y `class="img-fluid"` para que se vea en grande si no cambiales esa clase por `class="thumbnail"` y creo que eso seria todo

Comment: Hola Chris, no se termina de entender qué es lo que quieres hacer. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir una descripción más detallada del problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], que te servirán como guía para mejorar la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo, Pon el `.conatiner` y el `.row` fuera del `nav`

segundo, agrégale al elemento `nav` una clas `col-x`, por ejemplo:  `col-12`.

y por último, debes alinear todo el `ul` con `ml-auto`  (si es que quieres alinear a la derecha) ó  `mr-auto`  (si quieres alinear a la izquierda).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary n1 col-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01"></div>
      
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Caracteristicas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciono a la perfeccion, muchas gracias!